# How to Store Multiple records in My Array List from Azure mobile service Using API Code?

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps

I created `completeall2`  API in Azure Mobile service..

### My API Coding

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
var mssql = request.service.mssql;
var sql = "SELECT * from productmovement";
mssql.query(sql, {
    success: function(results) {            

                   response.send(200, results);

    }    })  };
```

What's Code for store this `results` into my `ArrayList<ProductMovement>` in my app..

Comment: Do you get the answer..if yes, then plzz share bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did to overcome this problem, is to call a different overload of invokeApi that returns a JsonElement, and then deserialise it into my objects like so:

```
mClient.invokeApi("productmovement",new ApiJsonOperationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JsonElement jsonElement, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) {
        GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonb.create();

        JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>()>
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            myObjects.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().toString(), MyObject.class));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see the Mobile Services reference for querying data from an Android client:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying

Comment: `productmovement` not a table..it's `views`...i joining 6 tables and store values in productmovement views..